# software for sketching derivatives from arbitrary functions drawn by hand

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, math-software

So, let's say I want to visualize the derivative of an arbitrary function and vice-versa. What software can I use to do this?  By arbitrary I  mean I just want to draw any function by hand and see the behavior of the derivative. I don't want to introduce an equation to graph its function but to draw the curve by using the pencil thing and the software to show its derivative.

Comment: Geogebra does it from what I remember, but it has the problem that every little hand twitch causes a massive spike and the derivative can be hard to read.

Comment: @Kaynex  can you show how to do it. I'm sorry I'm so lost

Comment: @Novato On Desmos, you can type $y = \frac{d}{dx}  f(x)$. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qnwpcyzch6) is an example illustrating this using a couple of functions.

Comment: Ok.The thing is I don't want to introduce an equation to get the graph of a function but to draw a curve and I from that I want the program to draw the curve of its derivative.

Comment: Define a very step $h$ (for example $h=10^{-4}$) and plot $g$ defined by $g(x):=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h.$

Comment: It's hard to do this nicely (i.e. with a by-hand sketchpad) without some kind of graphics programming or a tool I dont know of.... what if you choose say $n$ points (like drawing... kind of...) and then have a program connect them (e.g. via a spline) to give you your curve, after which you can have the program compute and plot the derivative as well (easy, since splines are polynomials).

Answer (score 1):

There is a freeware program called scanit, or (ScanIt) you can find at Softpedia. It will let you scan a line to produce a list of X,Y pairs that you can than load into Excel (or whatever) and calculate approximate dy/dx.